# The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your balance

Tags: payable, constructor, factory

This is one of my parent contract (child factory contract) functions that creates a child contract. The function should be provided with 3 arguments

```
    function breed(uint _number, uint _amount, address payable _beneficiary) public payable {
        childDong _childdong = new childDong(_number, _amount, _beneficiary);
    }
```

And here is my child contract constructor function which gets created every time the above function gets called.

```
    constructor(uint _number, uint _amount, address payable _beneficiary) payable {
        _number = number;
        _amount = amount;
        _beneficiary = beneficiary;
    }
```

Every time I want to execute the breed function from the parent contract, I encounter this issue in the terminal. Does anyone how i can overcome this issue.
[image: error on remix terminal]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is the child constructor also payable ? Do u want to send ether to the child contract !

Comment: Not actually, I saw it somewhere. Do you think removing it gonna help?

Comment: I thought primary calculations in the child contract would need some gas, because of this I was trying to send some ether along creating the child.

Comment: When you have “payable” in the constructor then u should send extra ether to your contract and that is not the ether to pay the transaction fee. The transaction fee and gas is handled separately. How are u calling the contract ?

Comment: what are u trying to do ? Do u want the users to transfer extra ether to ur contract to be able to call the breed function and create a child contract !?

Comment: About your last comment to make it maybe clearer :) The payable declaration has nothing to do with the gas that is consumed by your contract. Payable should be used when you want the user to explicitly send extra ether to the contract, those ethers are not used to pay the network fees and they will be owned by the smart contract and u need an additional function in the contract to spend them or they will get stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is not complete (calling breed function), it is a bit difficult to find the root cause of this error.
Moreover, I think the variable assignments in the constructor is not correct. In other words, an assignment statement causes the expression on the right-hand-side to be evaluated. If the left-hand-side is a variable, the value of the right-hand-side is assigned to that unevaluated variable.
In your case, all values of "number, amount, and beneficiary" are "0, 0, and zero bytes20", respectively. The correct code is: (I do not think this correction would solve your main error):

```
constructor(uint _number, uint _amount, address payable _beneficiary) payable {
    number = _number;
    amount = _amount;
    beneficiary = _beneficiary;
}
```